# How to ignore capitalization by useing django build-in methd?

Tags: python, django

There is a __contains method

```
contents.objects.filter(title__contains = 'live').order_by('-id')
```

It's equal to sql like

```
select * from contents where title like '%live%' order by id desc
```

the sql results maybe like this:

```
xxxxxx_live——sdf
xxxx_livess_sdd
.....
```

How to select data where title contains `Live` and `live`?
Does django has some build-in method?

Comment: What is "Live" data?

Comment: `title__icontains` maybe? It's useful for case insensitive queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can use `icontains` to match LIVE, Live, live, LIve.

```
contents.objects.filter(title__icontains='live').order_by('-id')
```

Comment: Oh yeah,That's it.